# THD calculated with amplitude instead of RMS

Tags: signal-processing, harmonics, total-harmonic-distortion

I have a digitized sinewave, and want to determine the THD of this waveform.

This is the equation I am familiar with for calculating THD:

$$
THD=\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}V_{n_{rms}}^2}}{V_{fund_{rms}}}
$$

A colleague of mine has been using a solution that substitutes the RMS voltage of the harmonics and fundamental with the amplitude. My colleague claims this is acceptable because \$ V_{rms} = V_{peak} / \sqrt2 \$ (for a sinwave), and we can simplify to the \$ V_{peak} \$ because \$ \sqrt2 \$ occurs in all terms.

Being able to skip calculating RMS seems like a nice performance improvement, but I am concerned as I can't readily see what it is costing me.

What do I lose using this method, are there any "gotchas" I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your colleague is correct.

$$
\sqrt{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} V_{nrms}^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2}V_{npeak}^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}V_{npeak}^2}
$$

As long as each \$V_{rms}\$ is referring to a sine wave.